# FFMPEG MP3 file size much larger than expected on Windows 10

Tags: windows, audio, ffmpeg, mp3

I've been using FFMPEG on Windows to:

1. Convert iTunes M4A files to MP3s (with a bit rate of 128k); and
2. Create 30 sec sample MP3s of the above MP3s (same bit rate).

When I run FFMEG on a Windows 7 64 bit machine, the size of the MP3s (both for 1. & 2.) is in line with the rough calculation of:

```
(Audio length in seconds) X (Bit rate)
```

For example, a 4 minute audio yields an approx. 3.7MB MP3 file; a 30 second sample MP3 is approx. 470KB.

However when I run the same FFMPEG binary (copied from the Windows 7 machine) on a Windows 10 64 bit machine, all of the MP3s (both for 1. and for 2.) are inflated by approx 5MB. I'm using the same batch file on both machines to execute FFMEG with the required parameters, so pretty confident the difference is not down to user error.

My questions are:

1. Why is there this apparent 5MB overhead on Windows 10? and more importantly;
2. What can I do to remove this?

The large file size is a problem as the sample MP3s are to be put on a website for people to listen to a snippet of the song, and the webpage with multiple  tags takes a long time to load completely (several minutes).

Here is the version and lib info:

`ffmpeg version 3.4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libmfx
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100`

And here are the command lines I'm using:

1. ffmpeg -i input.m4a -id3v2_version 3 -b:a 128k -output.mp3
2. ffmpeg -i input.m4a -ss 30 -t 30 -af "afade=in:st=30:d=5,afade=out:st=55:d=5" -id3v2_version 3 -b:a 128k -output.mp3

Comment: Share logs from both machines for conversion of the same file.

Comment: @Mulvya Good call - had -loglevel set to error, which was obscuring the fact that *video* (i.e. a PNG of the album cover) was being included in the MP3s. Didn't know that was possible. Still investigating - more to come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the FFMPEG switch -vn to remove the video stream from the output, and that dramatically reduced the size of the MP3s (down to what was expected).

Turns out there **was** a difference between the FFMPEG parameters being used on each machine. On one machine the "sample" MP3 was starting from the beginning of the track (-ss 0) and this was the one with the album cover art PNG embedded in the video stream). The other machine's parameters was starting the "sample" from 30 seconds in (-ss 30) and this was **not** include the album cover art.

Interesting difference - not sure if it's deliberate - but that explains what was happening.